# Visual studio 2017 does not recognize Docker For Windows is installed

Tags: visual-studio, docker

Working on solution with 2 WEBAPI projects, and 1 MVC/Angular UI project

all 3 are docker enabled.

The problem is when I try to run my docker-compose project with my .yml files i get this error msg:

**Visual Studio Container Tools requires Docker to be running before building, debugging or running a containerized project.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 311**

and when I start Visual Studio Elevated/admin, I get the following error msg

[image]

Its as if visual studio is not recognizing docker for windows is installed

Comment: Is the 'Docker for Windows' service running?

Comment: Yes, it's running. Docker seems to be working fine